# Once an opportunity line item will create update Opportunity's Account with maximun amount product

Tags: salesforce

trigger MaxProductAmount on OpportunityLineItem (after update) {
    Set opportunityIds = new Set();

```
        for (AggregateResult ar : [select Max(Quantity)opport1,Opportunity.AccountId from OpportunityLineItem 
                                   where Opportunity.AccountId in :accountIds]) {
                                       Decimal total = Decimal.valueOf(ar.get('opport1'));

                                       accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = ar.Opportunity.AccountId,Max_product_amount__c = total));
                                   }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `accountsToUpdate` doesn't exist in this code snippet, it won't even compile. `after update` event looks suspicious, probably should be `after insert, update, undelete` (I don't remember if opp line items go to recycle bin or are hard deleted). Query is bit wasteful, will go through all ops ever for this account when really you need to worry only about current `trigger.new` scope? But yeah, what is your question exactly, what doesn't work. Because what we see has lots of problems

Comment: my question is i want update most expensive product in account object when i write trigger on opportunityLineItem.